# Macro works only one selected cell ( doesn't work if 2 or more cells are selected)

Tags: excel, vba

I have this problem: my code is executed correctly only if 1 cell is selected, it doesn't work with multiple cells selection. What should be changed? Please help.

current code:

```
Sub adddate()
Dim cell As Range
Dim r As Range
Set r = Selection

For Each cell In Selection
If IsDate(r.Value) Then
Selection.Cells = DateAdd("d", 28, CDate(r))
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: See [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA macros](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros/28700020#28700020).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting selection in `r` and then using it. `cell` variable never comes in play.

```
Sub adddate()
Dim cell As Range
Dim r As Range
Set r = Selection

For Each cell In Selection.Celss
If IsDate(cell.Value2) Then 'r = selection, multiple cells can't be evaluated in IsDate, cell is just one single. cell
Selection.Cells = DateAdd("d", 28, CDate(r))
End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: what do you mean? didn't get you. replace `IsDate(r)` with `IsDate(cell)`, see the answer's code. Also one edit, for dates, use `value2` instead of `value`

Comment: Right, I got it now :) Thanks cyboashu. There is one more issue though: when I select multiple cells and there is value that is not date within selection, whe I run macro this non-date vlue gets converted into date. How do I fix that?

Comment: one more issue, means start another question, one thing at a time.:)

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks:)